# Is there a way to update comments when saving an Eclipse file?

Tags: java, eclipse, formatting

This isn't exactly a programming question, but my goal is to add a comment at the top of the class that shows when you last edited the file, updating when it saves. I know Eclipse can access the date and time, since adding a "Date Created:" comment was easy, but that's just editing the new file code templates so I would imagine it's not in the same area. I've been learning Java and Eclipse for about a year now, and this would be super helpful to keep track of files.

[Here's a picture in case I wasn't clear](https://i.stack.imgur.com/slA9R.png)

Comment: Tangential, but it’s less helpful than you might think (and generally the same information is available from source control).

Comment: You generally use a source control system such as Git or Svn to track updates. The "Local History" built in to Eclipse provides some support for showing you changes and even comparing different versions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, not out of the box. Someone could write a plug-in to do it, but as the comments have mentioned, once you're past a trivial example, this is usually the job for a source control system.